# Get value from relationed table, not his id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I have two tables:

Products

- id
- name
- category_id

Categories

- id
- name

In my models I have relations specified and when I get

\Product::all(); return looks something like:

```
id: 1
name: product Name
category_id: 1
```

Is it possible to get category name, not his id. I need something like this:

```
id: 1
name: product Name
category_name: electronics
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$products = App\Product::with('category')->get();
```

If you want to select the specific column from the category then, you can use

```
 $products = App\Product::with(['category'=>function($query){
      $query->select('name');
 }])->get();
```

This will give the product with the category if it have category.Then , you can use `foreach` loop to get the category like

```
foreach($products as $product){
    echo $product->id;
    echo $product->name;
    foreach($product->category as $cat){
       echo $cat->name;
    }
}
```